# Smooth Camera Movement with OpenGL

Tags: loops, opengl, camera, smoothing

I've been working with my own game engine for awhile now and I've been trying to get the input and controls to flow much more like a AAA FPS game, or at least a decent indie one. I've posted several topics in the past on this issue about making a smooth camera, and at the time of posting them, I had been satisfied with the results. Now however, I feel that it is not quite smooth enough, and I've switched the whole engine to SDL so I have control over the loop. (previously I was using GLUT). After changing everything to SDL, the mouse is smooth as butter, but the camera movement (walking) is still stutters and looks bad. I've implemented the last of Dwitter's game loop, the one with interpolation, and here is the relevant code:

```
int main (int argc,  char** argv)
{
    arg1 = argc;
    arg2 = argv;
    engineInit();
    //the loop has to stay here
    //kill all extra threads so they don't cause problems after we quit
    //gameloop
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    const int TPS = 20;
    const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TPS;
    const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5;
    int loops;
    long lastSec = 0;
    long nextGameTick = SDL_GetTicks();

    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            //do crap with events
            switch (event.type)
            {
                int x,y,button;
                case SDL_QUIT:
                SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_Quit();
                cout << "The window has been closed.\n";
                running = false;
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                    SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                    passiveMouse(x,y);
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
                   button =  SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                    mouseFunc(button,1,x,y);
                    break;
                 case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    keyboardDownFunc(event.key.keysym.sym);
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYUP:
                    keyboardUpFunc(event.key.keysym.sym);
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }

        }
        loops = 0;
        while (SDL_GetTicks()> nextGameTick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
            nextGameTick+=SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
            TickHandler.tps++;
            TickHandler.onTick();


            int tickTime = int(SDL_GetTicks()/1000);
            if (tickTime > lastSec+1)
            {
                TickHandler.tps = 0;
                lastSec = tickTime;
            }
        }
        TickHandler.interpolation = double(SDL_GetTicks() + SKIP_TICKS - nextGameTick )
        / double( SKIP_TICKS );
        TickHandler.onRender();
        render();
    }
    Console.consoleActivated = false;
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
    }
```

TickHandler.onRender() calls a few interpolated functions and here is the one that controls movement of the camera:

```
void renderTick(float intp)
{
    if (cameraPlayer == true)
    {
        Physics.pos3 = -camy;
        Physics.collisions();
        Input.applyGravity();
        if (Input.walking == true)
            Input.moveCameraFirstPerson(1*intp);
        else
        {
            roll = 0;
            Input.change = false;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the move camera first person:

```
void inputs::moveCameraFirstPerson(float speed)
{
    speed = speed*walkspeed;
    float radx = ((yaw+addedAngle)*MPI/180);
    camx -= (sinf(radx)/10)*speed;
    camz += (cosf(radx)/10)*speed;

    Physics.pos1 = -camx;
    Physics.pos2 = -camz;

    if (Physics.collided == true)
    {float radx = ((yaw+Input.addedAngle)*3.1415926535/180);
        camx += (sinf(radx)/20)*speed;
        camz -= (cosf(radx)/20)*speed;
        Physics.collided = false;

    }
    Client.x = camx;
    Client.z = camz;
    Client.y = camy;

    Projectile.x = camx;
    Projectile.z = camz;
}
```

I'd love if I could get this all sorted out, any help or references?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? If you ask for a code review, there's a dedicated StackExchange subsite for that.

Comment: @datenwolf I just wanted to  know what I was doing wrong with the code that would cause it to do that. It does run at the 20 tick per second an 60 frames as well. Changing the tps doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: While it is unlikely that your code is complicated enough to take longer than 1 ms between calls to `SDL_GetTicks (...)` in this example it is bad form to keep calling your timer's tick function over and over. Generally, you get a single ticked time at the beginning of a frame and use this value ***every where*** to ensure that the order your game logic occurs in does not affect things that are technically all supposed to happen at the same time. This becomes a much more serious issue when you use higher-resolution timers (SDL has a 1 ms timer, other frameworks can get you 10 ns or less).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I changed the code, and while that does make sense, the reference from the game loop doesn't do that. However, that doesn't stop the stuttering problem.